# Printing a mail with a picture in lotus notes cuts off right side for one user

Tags: printing, lotus-notes

The issue is about printing a mail that only consists of one picture. For most users the picture fits the page as you can see in the attached screenshot:

[image]

For one user the picture does not fit the page but is cut off on the right side. The picture is slightly bigger. You can even see this in the print preview. We checked all printer properties, especially the "scale graphics to 100%" option among others. We cannot find a obvious different in properties and even matching any property an restarting Lotus won't solve the issue.

Maybe someone knows issues like this and can help.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was caused by copy Excel Data as Pictures on Systems with different resolutions.